# Spring Security & Keycloak: Keep logged in

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm using Grails 4.x with following dependencies

```
    compile group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-spring-security-adapter', version: '12.0.2'
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.13.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.13.RELEASE"
```

and have configured via json (keycloak-credentials). With application.yaml, I set up

```
---
server:
    servlet:
        session:
            timeout: 259200
            tracking-modes: cookie
```

The problem is, that if I close the browser, I have to login again in my application. The cookies set are "OAuth_Token_Request_State" and "JSESSIONID" and both expire if browser is closed.

How can a sticky-login be achived?

Comment: Maybe your browser deletes cookies automatically after closing or you are using private windows? In general, the session.timeout property shall make the cookie expire after the given time

Comment: I checked this, it's not the case. All other cookies stay even if I close the browser. Beside, one of the above mentioned cookies should have a expiration date rather than "if browser is closed".

Comment: I'm wondering if this is enough, or if I need some sort of "inMemoryAuthentication"?